# Flutter: using dynamic Tabbar View and AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin

Tags: flutter, dart, tabs

I have a dynamic Tabbar that when I come to first position of that I add three Tab in first of my tabbar. and to save state of Any page of tabs used AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin. and when the new Tab is added the state of page is lost.

this is my code:
tab_block

```
class TabBloc extends Bloc<TabEvent, TabState> {
  TabBloc() : super(TabState.init()) {
    on<TabEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(state.addItem(event.addToEnd, event.currentPosition));
    });
  }
}
```

tab_event:

```
class TabEvent {
  final bool addToEnd;
  final int currentPosition;

  TabEvent({required this.addToEnd, required this.currentPosition});
}
```

tab_state:

```
class TabState {
  late final Tab tab;

  TabState({required this.tab});

  TabState.init() {
    SplayTreeMap<DateTime, String> items = SplayTreeMap();

    for (int i = -2; i <= 2; i++) {
      var dateTime = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: i));
      items[dateTime] = intl.DateFormat("EEE dd MMM").format(dateTime);
    }
    int tabPosition = 2;
    tab = Tab(count: items.length, items: items, position: tabPosition);
  }

  TabState copyWith(newTab) {
    return TabState(tab: newTab);
  }

  TabState addItem(bool addToEnd, int currentPosition) {
    SplayTreeMap<DateTime, String> items = tab.items;
    int position = currentPosition;
    if (addToEnd) {
      for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        var date = items.lastKey()!.add(const Duration(days: 1));
        items[date] = intl.DateFormat("EEE dd MMM").format(date);
      }
    } else {
      for (int i = -1; i >= -3; i--) {
        var date = items.firstKey()!.add(const Duration(days: -1));
        items[date] = intl.DateFormat("EEE dd MMM").format(date);
      }
      position += 3;
    }

    return TabState(
        tab: Tab(count: items.length, items: items, position: position));
  }
}

class Tab {
  int count;
  SplayTreeMap<DateTime, String> items;
  int position;

  Tab({required this.count, required this.items, required this.position});
}
```

main:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  getIt.registerFactory(() => bloc_tab.TabBloc());
  runApp(MultiBlocProvider(
    providers: [
      BlocProvider(create: (context) => getIt<bloc_tab.TabBloc>()),
    ],
    child: const MyApp2(),
  ));
}


class MyApp2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp2> createState() => _MyApp2State();
}

class _MyApp2State extends State<MyApp2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage2(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage2> createState() => _MyHomePage2State();
}

class _MyHomePage2State extends State<MyHomePage2>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;
  late int _currentCount;
  late int _currentPosition;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _currentPosition = BlocProvider.of<bloc_tab.TabBloc>(context).state.tab.position ?? 0;
    _currentCount = BlocProvider.of<bloc_tab.TabBloc>(context).state.tab.count;
    _tabController = TabController(
        length: _currentCount,
        vsync: this,
        initialIndex: _currentPosition);

    _tabController.addListener(onPositionChange);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<bloc_tab.TabBloc, bloc_tab.TabState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("ffddfdf"),
            bottom: PreferredSize(
                preferredSize: TabBar(
                        tabs: [],)
                    .preferredSize,
                child: Material(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(20, 75, 102, 1),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      TabBar(
                          isScrollable: true,
                          tabs: _getTabs(state.tab.items),
                          controller: _tabController),
                      Container(
                        height: 1,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              gradient: LinearGradient(
                                  colors: [
                            Colors.transparent,
                            Colors.white54,
                            Colors.white60,
                            Colors.white70,
                            Colors.white70,
                            Colors.white70,
                            Colors.white60,
                            Colors.white54,
                            Colors.transparent
                          ],
                                  begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  end: Alignment.centerRight))),
                    ],
                  ),
                )),
            backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(85, 200, 84, 1),
          ),
          body: Column(children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(
                controller: _tabController,
                children: getWidgets(state.tab.items)
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        );
      },
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (_tabController.length != state.tab.count) {
          _tabController.removeListener(onPositionChange);
          _tabController.dispose();

          _currentPosition = state.tab.position;

          if (_currentPosition > state.tab.count - 1) {
            _currentPosition = state.tab.count - 1;
            _currentPosition = _currentPosition < 0 ? 0 : _currentPosition;
          }

          _currentCount = state.tab.count;
            _tabController = TabController(
              length: state.tab.count,
              vsync: this,
              initialIndex: _currentPosition,
            );
            _tabController.addListener(onPositionChange);
        }
      },
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _getTabs(Map<DateTime, String> items) {
    List<Widget> tabs = [];
    items.forEach((key, value) {
      tabs.add(Tab(
        text: value,
      ));
    });
    return tabs;
  }

  Widget getWidget(String widgetNumber) {
    return Center(
      child: Text("Widget nr: $widgetNumber"),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> getWidgets(Map<DateTime, String> items) {
    List<Widget> screens = [];
    items.forEach((key, value) {
      screens.add(TabPage(dateTime: key,));
    });
    return screens;
  }

  onPositionChange() {
    if (!_tabController.indexIsChanging) {
      _currentPosition = _tabController.index;
      if (_tabController.index == _tabController.length - 1) {
        BlocProvider.of<bloc_tab.TabBloc>(context).add(bloc_tab.TabEvent(
            addToEnd: true, currentPosition: _tabController.index));
      } else if (_tabController.index == 0) {
        BlocProvider.of<bloc_tab.TabBloc>(context).add(bloc_tab.TabEvent(
            addToEnd: false, currentPosition: _tabController.index));
      }
    }
  }
}

class TabPage extends StatefulWidget {

  DateTime dateTime;

  TabPage({Key? key, required this.dateTime}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TabPage> createState() => _TabPageState();
}

class _TabPageState extends State<TabPage>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  late Future<Fixture> futureFixture;



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureFixture = fetchFixture(widget.dateTime);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return FutureBuilder<Fixture>(
      future: futureFixture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.leagues!.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return MatchItem(snapshot.data!.leagues![index].matches!.length,
                    league: snapshot.data!.leagues![index]);
              });
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(child: Text("error - ${snapshot.error}"));
        }

        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive {
    return true;
  }
}
```

[this is 12/09/2022 and its right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D1Fc.png)
when I go to first tab (position 0) and add 3 tab

[this is 12/06/2022 and its wrong its show game of 12/09](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U040I.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to set a unique [`Key`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html) when constructing my TabPage :

```dart
List<Widget> getWidgets(Map<DateTime, String> items) {
    List<Widget> screens = [];
    items.forEach((key, value) {
        screens.add(TabPage(key: Key(value),dateTime: key,));
    });
    return screens;
}
```